# How to redraw views in onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I'm getting data to fill my listView using AsyncTask. I'm changing adapter for listview in `onPostExecute()`

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<JSONObject> result) {

    MarkersListAdapter adapter = (MarkersListAdapter) this.markersList.getAdapter();

    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(result);

    this.markersList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then I want to make some changes to the new views but ListView is populated with new views after program return from `onPostExecute()`. I want to force android to fill my listview when in `onPostExecute()`. I've tried `notifyDatasetChanged()` for adapter and `invalidate()` for listview but none worked.

Comment: What kind of changes..? Why don't post what you have tried..

Comment: Changes in item graphics depending on some other data. I don't think this code is relative to the case. I'm using `getChildAt(i)` to retrieve views.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this modifing the list and invalidating the listView.

First set the adapter to the listView.

```
listView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_cell_layout, objList));
```

Whenever you need to refresh the list, just make changes to objList and call invalidate to the listView, like this:

```
objList.remove(1);
listView.invalidateViews();
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Well, actually it doesn't work for me. Nothing happens. `getChildAt(i)` returns null. Views shows up after just few debugger steps after end of `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Have you added a non-null list when creating your ListAdapter?

Comment: Nope. I initialize it like that: `ArrayList<JSONObject> result = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(); MarkersListAdapter adapter = new MarkersListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.cito_select_markers_row, result); markersList.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Ok, do your **ArrayList<JSONObject> objList** global. At your **onPostExecute**, do `objList.addAll(result); markersList.invalidateViews();`